# How to use word2vec2tensor in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am following the following gensim tutorial to transform my word2vec model to tensor.
Link to the tutorial: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/word2vec2tensor.html

More specifically, I ran the following command

```
python -m gensim.scripts.word2vec2tensor -i C:\Users\Emi\Desktop\word2vec\model_name -o C:\Users\Emi\Desktop\word2vec
```

However, I get the following error for the above command.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

When I use `model.wv.save_word2vec_format(model_name)` to save my model (as mentioned in the following link: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1847) and then use the above command I get the following error.

```
ValueError: invalid vector on line 1 (is this really the text format?)
```

Just wondering if I have made any mistakes in the syntax of the commads. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with the MovieLens dataset. I was initially using the complete movie name as the word to train the word2vec model. Apparently when you save the model like that something (spaces, quotation marks, etc. I guess) messes up everything and it can't read it back.
When I changed my words to movie IDs (numbers saved as strings, with no spaces or quotations) everything worked fine with word2vec2tensor.
This is discussed [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/388#issuecomment-378681845) on GitHub.

Comment: @MiladShahidi thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the following code:

```
model = gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load(file_name)

max_size = len(model.wv.vocab)-1
w2v = np.zeros((max_size,model.layer1_size))

if not os.path.exists('projections'):
    os.makedirs('projections')

with open("projections/metadata.tsv", 'w+') as file_metadata:

    for i, word in enumerate(model.wv.index2word[:max_size]):

        #store the embeddings of the word
        w2v[i] = model.wv[word]

        #write the word to a file 
        file_metadata.write(word + '\n')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    embedding = tf.Variable(w2v, trainable=False, name='embedding')
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('projections', sess.graph)
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embed= config.embeddings.add()
embed.tensor_name = 'embedding'
embed.metadata_path = 'metadata.tsv'
projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)
saver.save(sess, 'projections/model.ckpt', global_step=max_size)
```

Comment: why `max_size = len(model.wv.vocab)-1` ? why -1?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not compatible with `gensim.scripts.word2vec2tensor()`. You might need to save your model using `model.wv.save_word2vec_format()`.

I'm guessing you used `model.save()` which calls pickle in the background (see [utils documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.SaveLoad)). Alternatively, `model.wv.save_word2vec_format()` will save word vectors "in a format compatible with the original word2vec implementation" as noted in the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec). This format is consistent with `gensim.scripts.word2vec2tensor()`